# How to instantiate an object in ViewModel and edit that in another ViewModel or user control

Tags: c#, wpf, object, mvvm, binding

I'm new to c# and mvvm.
I have a class that has many properties, and because of that, it is not possible to present every property to user in one page. Therefore, I decided to break the UI into 4 different part. I designed one user control for each of these parts.
As of now, I have 4 different user controls which are presented to user with the help of a side bar selection.
However, I still have one object to work with and it is not possible to break the object too.

The problem is I cant access to object from user controls' code behind.  It means that I can bind object with UI but I'm not able to change parameters in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

On one hand you talk about MVVM and data-binding, but then on the other hand you talk about modifying changing parameters in code-behind. These are antithetical design patterns. Pick one!

Comment: Thank you.
you are absolutely right. I'm new to MVVM and I'm trying to learn the command system. but meanwhile I wanted my application to work. just enough for me to learn mvvm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing MVVM then, as you know you have the View (UI e.g. Page1.xaml) in XAML, with code behind (Page1.xaml.cs) these then use a ViewModel (e.g. Page1ViewModel.cs) as their data context, i.e. where they can access the Model.

You do not have to have a one-to-one correlation of Views, ViewModels and Models.
You can have more than one View use the same ViewModel as its data context and you can have a ViewModel contain yet more ViewModels and a ViewModel can reference several Models if required.

So in your situation I'd have several pages reference the same ViewModel.